# Pack's CLI buildpack package command returns ERROR unknown configuration elements

Tags: buildpack

I'm trying to build my custom buildpack, I have a buildpack.toml file:

```
api = "0.5"

[buildpack]
id = "localhost:5000/test-buildpack"
version = "0.0.1"
```

I'm using command:

> pack buildpack package test-buildpack --config ./buildpack.toml

unfortunately Pack CLI returns error:

> ERROR: reading config: unknown configuration elements api, buildpack.id, buildpack.version in ./buildpack.toml

What am I missing?

Pack CLI version: 0.18.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config file that `pack buildpack package` expects is the `package.toml` file not the `buildpack.toml` file.

See -

https://buildpacks.io/docs/reference/config/package-config/
https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/cli/pack_buildpack_package/

The `package.toml` file isn't always necessary and you can just omit passing the `--config` flag and/or creating a `package.toml` file if you are creating a standalone buildpack which doesn't depend on other buildpacks.

Comment: Skipping the `--config` flag did the trick. Thanks a lot!